# have "Symbol not found: _PyCMethod_New" when import pyexiv2

Tags: python, pyexiv2

I'm trying to copy exif informations from an image tiff to another but I have this error when I importinf pyexiv2.

```
  File "test.py", line 359, in <module>
    import pyexiv2
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/beeslife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyexiv2/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    import libexiv2python
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/beeslife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libexiv2python.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCMethod_New
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python39.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python39.dylib
```

I use macOs Catalina and have the last version of python3 and using py3exiv2 .

I dont know how to solve this problem